# No lines for my D3 graph

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to convert [this](https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91) D3 example from version 4 to version 5 but for some reason I can't get the lines working on the graph.. 
I get no errors and the values are updated when I move my mouse but I see no lines!
I cant understand if I am missing something. What's wrong with the code?

In addition I want a function that gets the (String) data from a jason file and convert it to numbers

```js
var data = [
    {"date": "20111001",  "New York": "63.4",  "San Francisco": "62.7",  "Austin": "72.2"},
    {"date": "20111002",  "New York": "58.0",  "San Francisco": "59.9",  "Austin": "67.7"},
    {"date": "20111002",  "New York": "58.0",  "San Francisco": "59.9",  "Austin": "67.7"},
    {"date": "20111003",  "New York": "53.3",  "San Francisco": "59.1",  "Austin": "69.4"},
    {"date": "20111004",  "New York": "55.7",  "San Francisco": "58.8",  "Austin": "68.0"},
    {"date": "20111005",  "New York": "64.2",  "San Francisco": "58.7",  "Austin": "72.4"},
    {"date": "20111006",  "New York": "58.8",  "San Francisco": "57.0",  "Austin": "77.0"},
    {"date": "20111007",  "New York": "57.9",  "San Francisco": "56.7",  "Austin": "82.3"},
    {"date": "20111008",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "56.8",  "Austin": "78.9"},
    {"date": "20111009",  "New York": "69.3",  "San Francisco": "56.7",  "Austin": "68.8"},
    {"date": "20111010",  "New York": "71.2",  "San Francisco": "60.1",  "Austin": "68.7"},
    {"date": "20111011",  "New York": "68.7",  "San Francisco": "61.1",  "Austin": "70.3"},
    {"date": "20111012",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "61.5",  "Austin": "75.3"},
    {"date": "20111013",  "New York": "63.0",  "San Francisco": "64.3",  "Austin": "76.6"},
    {"date": "20111014",  "New York": "66.9",  "San Francisco": "67.1",  "Austin": "66.6"},
    {"date": "20111015",  "New York": "61.7",  "San Francisco": "64.6",  "Austin": "68.0"},
    {"date": "20111016",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "61.6",  "Austin": "70.6"},
    {"date": "20111017",  "New York": "62.8",  "San Francisco": "61.1",  "Austin": "71.1"},
    {"date": "20111018",  "New York": "60.8",  "San Francisco": "59.2",  "Austin": "70.0"},
    {"date": "20111019",  "New York": "62.1",  "San Francisco": "58.9",  "Austin": "61.6"},
    {"date": "20111020",  "New York": "65.1",  "San Francisco": "57.2",  "Austin": "57.4"},
    {"date": "20111021",  "New York": "55.6",  "San Francisco": "56.4",  "Austin": "64.3"},
    {"date": "20111022",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "60.7",  "Austin": "72.4"},
    {"date": "20111023",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "65.1",  "Austin": "72.4"},
    {"date": "20111024",  "New York": "54.8",  "San Francisco": "60.9",  "Austin": "72.5"},
    {"date": "20111025",  "New York": "57.9",  "San Francisco": "56.1",  "Austin": "72.7"},
    {"date": "20111026",  "New York": "54.6",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "73.4"},
    {"date": "20111027",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "56.1",  "Austin": "70.7"},
    {"date": "20111028",  "New York": "42.5",  "San Francisco": "58.1",  "Austin": "56.8"},
    {"date": "20111029",  "New York": "40.9",  "San Francisco": "57.5",  "Austin": "51.0"},
    {"date": "20111030",  "New York": "38.6",  "San Francisco": "57.7",  "Austin": "54.9"},
    {"date": "20111031",  "New York": "44.2",  "San Francisco": "55.1",  "Austin": "58.8"},
    {"date": "20111101",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "57.9",  "Austin": "62.6"},
    {"date": "20111102",  "New York": "47.2",  "San Francisco": "64.6",  "Austin": "71.0"},
    {"date": "20111103",  "New York": "50.1",  "San Francisco": "56.2",  "Austin": "58.4"},
    {"date": "20111104",  "New York": "50.1",  "San Francisco": "50.5",  "Austin": "45.1"},
    {"date": "20111105",  "New York": "43.5",  "San Francisco": "51.3",  "Austin": "52.2"},
    {"date": "20111106",  "New York": "43.8",  "San Francisco": "52.6",  "Austin": "73.0"},
    {"date": "20111107",  "New York": "48.9",  "San Francisco": "51.4",  "Austin": "75.4"},
    {"date": "20111108",  "New York": "55.5",  "San Francisco": "50.6",  "Austin": "72.1"},
    {"date": "20111109",  "New York": "53.7",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "56.6"},
    {"date": "20111110",  "New York": "57.7",  "San Francisco": "55.6",  "Austin": "55.4"},
    {"date": "20111111",  "New York": "48.5",  "San Francisco": "53.9",  "Austin": "46.7"},
    {"date": "20111112",  "New York": "46.8",  "San Francisco": "54.0",  "Austin": "62.0"},
    {"date": "20111113",  "New York": "51.1",  "San Francisco": "53.8",  "Austin": "71.6"},
    {"date": "20111114",  "New York": "56.8",  "San Francisco": "53.5",  "Austin": "75.5"},
    {"date": "20111115",  "New York": "59.7",  "San Francisco": "53.4",  "Austin": "72.1"},
    {"date": "20111116",  "New York": "56.5",  "San Francisco": "52.2",  "Austin": "65.7"},
    {"date": "20111117",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "52.7",  "Austin": "56.8"},
    {"date": "20111118",  "New York": "41.5",  "San Francisco": "53.1",  "Austin": "49.9"},
    {"date": "20111119",  "New York": "44.3",  "San Francisco": "49.0",  "Austin": "71.7"},
    {"date": "20111120",  "New York": "54.0",  "San Francisco": "50.4",  "Austin": "77.7"},
    {"date": "20111121",  "New York": "54.1",  "San Francisco": "51.1",  "Austin": "76.4"},
    {"date": "20111122",  "New York": "49.4",  "San Francisco": "52.3",  "Austin": "68.8"},
    {"date": "20111123",  "New York": "50.0",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "57.0"},
    {"date": "20111124",  "New York": "44.0",  "San Francisco": "55.1",  "Austin": "55.5"},
    {"date": "20111125",  "New York": "50.3",  "San Francisco": "51.5",  "Austin": "61.6"},
    {"date": "20111126",  "New York": "52.1",  "San Francisco": "53.6",  "Austin": "64.1"},
    {"date": "20111127",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "52.3",  "Austin": "51.1"},
    {"date": "20111128",  "New York": "57.2",  "San Francisco": "51.0",  "Austin": "43.0"}
    ];
        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 80,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
          },
          width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d");
    
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width]);
    
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
    
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
          .scale(x);
    
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
          .scale(y);
    
        var line = d3.line()
          .curve(d3.curveBasis)
          .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.date);
          })
          .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.temperature);
          });
    
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
        color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
          return key !== "date";
        }));
    
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        });
    
        var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
          return {
            name: name,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
              return {
                date: d.date,
                temperature: +d[name]
              };
            })
          };
        });
    
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.date;
        }));
    
        y.domain([
          d3.min(cities, function(c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
              return v.temperature;
            });
          }),
          d3.max(cities, function(c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
              return v.temperature;
            });
          })
        ]);
    
        var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
          .data(cities)
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'legend');
    
        legend.append('rect')
          .attr('x', width - 20)
          .attr('y', function(d, i) {
            return i * 20;
          })
          .attr('width', 10)
          .attr('height', 10)
          .style('fill', function(d) {
            return color(d.name);
          });
    
        legend.append('text')
          .attr('x', width - 8)
          .attr('y', function(d, i) {
            return (i * 20) + 9;
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
          });
    
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);
    
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Temperature (ºF)");
    
        var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
          .data(cities)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "city");
    
        city.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(d.values);
          })
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return color(d.name);
          });
    
        city.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) {
            return {
              name: d.name,
              value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
            };
          })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
          })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
          });
    
        var mouseG = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");
    
        mouseG.append("path") 
          .attr("class", "mouse-line")
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("stroke-width", "1px")
          .style("opacity", "0");
          
        var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');
    
        var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
          .data(cities)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");
    
        mousePerLine.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 7)
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return color(d.name);
          })
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("stroke-width", "1px")
          .style("opacity", "0");
    
        mousePerLine.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");
    
        mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
          .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
          .attr('height', height)
          .attr('fill', 'none')
          .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
          .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
              .style("opacity", "0");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
              .style("opacity", "0");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
              .style("opacity", "0");
          })
          .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
              .style("opacity", "1");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
              .style("opacity", "1");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
              .style("opacity", "1");
          })
          .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
            var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
              .attr("d", function() {
                var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
                d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
                return d;
              });
    
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                console.log(width/mouse[0])
                var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                    bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
                    idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);
                
                var beginning = 0,
                    end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                    target = null;
    
                while (true){
                  target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                  pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                  if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                      break;
                  }
                  if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
                  else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                  else break; //position found
                }
                
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                  .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));              
                return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
              });
          });
```

```css
body {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
        
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        
        .x.axis path {
          display: none;
        }
        
        .line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: steelblue;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are drawn, they're just drawn exceptionally smooshed to the left.

The issue is that you are formatting the time, not parsing it:

```js
var date = "20111127";

var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d");
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

console.log("formatted: " + formatDate(date));
console.log("parsed: " + parseDate(date));
```

```html
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

It just so happens that your date strings could be parsed as a time *and* provided as the input for formatting. Which is why no errors are seen.

The reason for the smooshing is interesting. The input string was read as seconds since the beginning of the epoch, and was formatted as yearmonthday, which formats them all as the same day (given the numbers): 19691231 *(in my timezone, which is why it's pre-epoch)*. This gets read as seconds since the beginning of epoch *again*, this time by the scale. As each point has the same time, the beginning and end points of the domain are the same and the scale breaks a bit.

Updated snippet:

```js
   var data = [
{"date": "20111001",  "New York": "63.4",  "San Francisco": "62.7",  "Austin": "72.2"},
{"date": "20111002",  "New York": "58.0",  "San Francisco": "59.9",  "Austin": "67.7"},
{"date": "20111002",  "New York": "58.0",  "San Francisco": "59.9",  "Austin": "67.7"},
{"date": "20111003",  "New York": "53.3",  "San Francisco": "59.1",  "Austin": "69.4"},
{"date": "20111004",  "New York": "55.7",  "San Francisco": "58.8",  "Austin": "68.0"},
{"date": "20111005",  "New York": "64.2",  "San Francisco": "58.7",  "Austin": "72.4"},
{"date": "20111006",  "New York": "58.8",  "San Francisco": "57.0",  "Austin": "77.0"},
{"date": "20111007",  "New York": "57.9",  "San Francisco": "56.7",  "Austin": "82.3"},
{"date": "20111008",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "56.8",  "Austin": "78.9"},
{"date": "20111009",  "New York": "69.3",  "San Francisco": "56.7",  "Austin": "68.8"},
{"date": "20111010",  "New York": "71.2",  "San Francisco": "60.1",  "Austin": "68.7"},
{"date": "20111011",  "New York": "68.7",  "San Francisco": "61.1",  "Austin": "70.3"},
{"date": "20111012",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "61.5",  "Austin": "75.3"},
{"date": "20111013",  "New York": "63.0",  "San Francisco": "64.3",  "Austin": "76.6"},
{"date": "20111014",  "New York": "66.9",  "San Francisco": "67.1",  "Austin": "66.6"},
{"date": "20111015",  "New York": "61.7",  "San Francisco": "64.6",  "Austin": "68.0"},
{"date": "20111016",  "New York": "61.8",  "San Francisco": "61.6",  "Austin": "70.6"},
{"date": "20111017",  "New York": "62.8",  "San Francisco": "61.1",  "Austin": "71.1"},
{"date": "20111018",  "New York": "60.8",  "San Francisco": "59.2",  "Austin": "70.0"},
{"date": "20111019",  "New York": "62.1",  "San Francisco": "58.9",  "Austin": "61.6"},
{"date": "20111020",  "New York": "65.1",  "San Francisco": "57.2",  "Austin": "57.4"},
{"date": "20111021",  "New York": "55.6",  "San Francisco": "56.4",  "Austin": "64.3"},
{"date": "20111022",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "60.7",  "Austin": "72.4"},
{"date": "20111023",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "65.1",  "Austin": "72.4"},
{"date": "20111024",  "New York": "54.8",  "San Francisco": "60.9",  "Austin": "72.5"},
{"date": "20111025",  "New York": "57.9",  "San Francisco": "56.1",  "Austin": "72.7"},
{"date": "20111026",  "New York": "54.6",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "73.4"},
{"date": "20111027",  "New York": "54.4",  "San Francisco": "56.1",  "Austin": "70.7"},
{"date": "20111028",  "New York": "42.5",  "San Francisco": "58.1",  "Austin": "56.8"},
{"date": "20111029",  "New York": "40.9",  "San Francisco": "57.5",  "Austin": "51.0"},
{"date": "20111030",  "New York": "38.6",  "San Francisco": "57.7",  "Austin": "54.9"},
{"date": "20111031",  "New York": "44.2",  "San Francisco": "55.1",  "Austin": "58.8"},
{"date": "20111101",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "57.9",  "Austin": "62.6"},
{"date": "20111102",  "New York": "47.2",  "San Francisco": "64.6",  "Austin": "71.0"},
{"date": "20111103",  "New York": "50.1",  "San Francisco": "56.2",  "Austin": "58.4"},
{"date": "20111104",  "New York": "50.1",  "San Francisco": "50.5",  "Austin": "45.1"},
{"date": "20111105",  "New York": "43.5",  "San Francisco": "51.3",  "Austin": "52.2"},
{"date": "20111106",  "New York": "43.8",  "San Francisco": "52.6",  "Austin": "73.0"},
{"date": "20111107",  "New York": "48.9",  "San Francisco": "51.4",  "Austin": "75.4"},
{"date": "20111108",  "New York": "55.5",  "San Francisco": "50.6",  "Austin": "72.1"},
{"date": "20111109",  "New York": "53.7",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "56.6"},
{"date": "20111110",  "New York": "57.7",  "San Francisco": "55.6",  "Austin": "55.4"},
{"date": "20111111",  "New York": "48.5",  "San Francisco": "53.9",  "Austin": "46.7"},
{"date": "20111112",  "New York": "46.8",  "San Francisco": "54.0",  "Austin": "62.0"},
{"date": "20111113",  "New York": "51.1",  "San Francisco": "53.8",  "Austin": "71.6"},
{"date": "20111114",  "New York": "56.8",  "San Francisco": "53.5",  "Austin": "75.5"},
{"date": "20111115",  "New York": "59.7",  "San Francisco": "53.4",  "Austin": "72.1"},
{"date": "20111116",  "New York": "56.5",  "San Francisco": "52.2",  "Austin": "65.7"},
{"date": "20111117",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "52.7",  "Austin": "56.8"},
{"date": "20111118",  "New York": "41.5",  "San Francisco": "53.1",  "Austin": "49.9"},
{"date": "20111119",  "New York": "44.3",  "San Francisco": "49.0",  "Austin": "71.7"},
{"date": "20111120",  "New York": "54.0",  "San Francisco": "50.4",  "Austin": "77.7"},
{"date": "20111121",  "New York": "54.1",  "San Francisco": "51.1",  "Austin": "76.4"},
{"date": "20111122",  "New York": "49.4",  "San Francisco": "52.3",  "Austin": "68.8"},
{"date": "20111123",  "New York": "50.0",  "San Francisco": "54.6",  "Austin": "57.0"},
{"date": "20111124",  "New York": "44.0",  "San Francisco": "55.1",  "Austin": "55.5"},
{"date": "20111125",  "New York": "50.3",  "San Francisco": "51.5",  "Austin": "61.6"},
{"date": "20111126",  "New York": "52.1",  "San Francisco": "53.6",  "Austin": "64.1"},
{"date": "20111127",  "New York": "49.6",  "San Francisco": "52.3",  "Austin": "51.1"},
{"date": "20111128",  "New York": "57.2",  "San Francisco": "51.0",  "Austin": "43.0"}
];
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(x);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(y);

    var line = d3.line()
      .curve(d3.curveBasis)
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      // coerce input strings to number:
      d["San Francisco"] = +d["San Francisco"];
      d["Austin"] = +d["Austin"]
      d["New York"] = +d["New York"]
      
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") 
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width/mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

            while (true){
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));              
            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
          });
      });
```

```css
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

*As you also indicated you wanted to coerce input strings to numbers, JSON strings are coerced to numbers in the data.forEach function using the unary +, you could do this dynamically by iterating through each property*

Comment: Thank you again Andrew.. You're helping me a lot